# How to gracefully handle SoapMessageCreationException?

Tags: exception, soap, spring-ws

I am faced with a very tricky scenario, I have a web-service using SOAP 1.2 and I would like to gracefully handle the exception in case a message was sent with SOAP 1.1 header instead of 1.2.

Currently, my messageFactory implementation is SAAJ, and it throws a SoapMessageCreationException when I send 1.1 headers, and my code below does not work and does not catch the error properly:

```
@Bean
    public SoapFaultMappingExceptionResolver exceptionResolver(){
        SoapFaultMappingExceptionResolver exceptionResolver = new DetailSoapFaultDefinitionExceptionResolver();

        SoapFaultDefinition faultDefinition = new SoapFaultDefinition();
        faultDefinition.setFaultCode(SoapFaultDefinition.SERVER);
        exceptionResolver.setDefaultFault(faultDefinition);

        Properties errorMappings = new Properties();
        errorMappings.setProperty(Exception.class.getName(), SoapFaultDefinition.SERVER.toString());
        errorMappings.setProperty(ServiceFaultException.class.getName(), SoapFaultDefinition.SERVER.toString());
        exceptionResolver.setExceptionMappings(errorMappings);
        exceptionResolver.setOrder(1);
        return exceptionResolver;
    }
```

I took the example from https://memorynotfound.com/spring-ws-add-detail-soapfault-exception-handling/ however it does not seem to work in my case.

The only approach I have found that works is [How to return custom SOAP Error from Spring Boot Endpoint Service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53665662/how-to-return-custom-soap-error-from-spring-boot-endpoint-service) which to be is very much an overkill.

If anyone has come across this issue before, I would love some pointers!